# Why does Guava (14.0.1) MultiMap putAll not compile with Groovy @TypeChecked?

Tags: groovy, guava

I have the following groovy code:

```
import com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked

@TypeChecked
class TestMulti {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListMultimap<String, Dummy> multi = LinkedListMultimap.create()
        List<Dummy> l = [new Dummy(x: 1)]
        multi.putAll("TEST", l)
        println multi
    }
}

class Dummy {
    int x
}
```

With guava-14.0.1, this code does not compile with the error:

```
Error:(11, 9) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method com.google.common.collect.Multimap#putAll(java.lang.String, java.util.List <Dummy>). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
```

But from what I can tell, that method should exist just fine. The docs list:

```
public boolean putAll(@Nullable K key,
                      Iterable<? extends V> values)
```

on `class LinkedListMultimap<K,V>`

and the same code runs fine without `@TypeChecked`.

(Note that the problem seems to be missing from versions of guava since 15.0, but for the moment, I am interested in why this code does not compile on 14.0.1 and earlier. I did not see anything in the change notes to indicate that this was something intentionally fixed, and it looks like it *should* work.)

Why doesn't this compile?

Comment: I put `@Grab('com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1')` on the script and tried with groovy 2.3.6 running and compiling.  Both worked.  Could you please state the groovy version too?  And are you running this directly on command line or with some build tool or from an IDE?

Comment: Bah, the issue is because I was using the wrong version of groovy. 2.2.0 has the issue. It works when I use 2.3.6. *sigh* I could have sworn I had tested this with the latest groovy. It must have only been while I was testing newer guava. Oh well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a problem in groovy 2.2. When I switch to groovy 2.3.6, it compiles fine.